# The configuration key "page_range" pagination

Tags: symfony

after several hours of setup, I still have this error:

> The configuration key "page_range" is unsupported for definition "knp_paginator"

If I move code on the left, I have this error: sometimes invalid yaml, and sometimes knp_paginator not found
my file services.yaml

parameters:

```
locale: 'en'
```

services:

```
_defaults:
    autowire: true
    autoconfigure: true
    public: false

App\:
    resource: '../src/*'
    exclude: '../src/{DependencyInjection,Entity,Migrations,Tests,Kernel.php}'


App\Controller\:
    resource: '../src/Controller'
    tags: ['controller.service_arguments']


knp_paginator:
  page_range: 5
  default_options:
    page_name: page
    sort_field_name: sort
    sort_direction_name: direction
    distinct: true
    filter_field_name: filterField
    filter_value_name: filterValue
  template:
    pagination: '@KnpPaginator/Pagination/sliding.html.twig'
    sortable: '@KnpPaginator/Pagination/sortable_link.html.twig'
    filtration: '@KnpPaginator/Pagination/filtration.html.twig'
```

and my file controller

```
    /**
     * @var $paginator \Knp\Component\Pager\PaginatorInterface
    */
    $resultatEleves = $eleveRepository->findAll()  ;
    $paginator = $this->get('knp_paginator');

    $pagination = $paginator->paginate(
        $resultatEleves,
        $request->query->getInt('page', 1),
        $request->query->getInt('limit', 5)
    );
```

(...)
after in line 79:

```
'eleves'=> $pagination,
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all, you dont have to put 'knp_paginator' node to services.yaml
you can create knp_paginator.yaml in config dir or you can add into the config.yaml.
Also you cant pass the findAll results, you have to pass query into the paginator.

more working example you can find at
https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/802/how-to-install-the-knppaginatorbundle-to-paginate-doctrine-queries-in-symfony-4